A book about the Second Coming of Jesus, but the supposed Messiah is actually Satan
I'm trying to find a book (or maybe a series of 2 or 3 books, I can't remember) about the Second Coming of Jesus. I read it about 25 years ago, and the author was a male.
In the book(s) Jesus returns to earth and starts making miracles, and at a certain point he lifts the weight of the Original Sin from humanity.
This guy is actually Satan, and the miracle of removing Original Sin is actually a temporary suspension of the toll that Hell imposes on people.
I vaguely remember about the Messiah/Satan becoming a sort of worldwide known celebrity, but a little group of people opposes him and ends being the only true saved persons that can go to Paradise, while the rest of humanity goes to Hell.
The overall tone was serious and mature, definitely not a young adult book.

Fits the vague shape of the Left Behind series, although my knowledge of it is pretty thin

Do you recall if the book started with The Rapture?

Also kind of fits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ_Clone_Trilogy although I can't find anything about the cancellation of original sin.

Isn't it the Apocalypse of John? Some plot elements do fit in. Good read, well written, even if not the story you're looking for.

@Radhil definitely not it, but it seems interesting, I'll give it a try!

@fez can't remember...

@FrançoisJurain are you talking about THAT Apocalypse of John? Not sure if I could like it... :D

@FuzzyBoots that's amazing, it actually could be it! Everything fits with my vague memories, you could have hit the target! I'll check better and eventually accept your answer, thanks again

This matches in some aspects to the Christ Clone Trilogy by James BeauSeigneur.

The trilogy starts with In His Image, where living human cells discovered on the Turin shroud are used to clone a child, Christopher Goodman. The book follows Goodman's story by telling the tale of Decker Hawthorne, a journalist and the main character of the series. Among the main events covered in this book are the creation of Christopher, the rapture and Christopher's progress to becoming a key figure in the United Nations.
The trilogy continues with the Birth of an Age, in which a series of disasters and plagues assault the earth and its inhabitants. Towards the end of this book, Christopher is killed and then resurrected.
Finally in Acts of God, there is coverage of further natural disasters and the realization of Christopher's true identity and motives. This book follows through to the end of the world and life afterwards.

However, I do not remember any scenes where he cancels Original Sin.
